# How to read rest of line with spaces after reading couple of strings in C

Tags: c, input, fgets

My input looks like this:

```
save 001 Some very long string with spaces... after three dots there , is also a comma
```

After this I call type:

```
load 001
```

And It should give me output:

```
Some very long string with spaces... after three dots there , is also a comma
```

I'm trying but nothing seems to work for example:

```
while ((scanf("%s %s", mode, key)) != EOF) {
    if (strcmp(mode, "save") == 0) { 
        getchar();
        fgets(data, 100, stdin);
        root = save(root, key, data);
        root = balance_RBT(root, blc);
    }
    if (strcmp(mode, "load") == 0) {
        load(root, key); 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the whole code so we could have better understanding regarding what do you want

Comment: Shouldn't it be Else If in the code line number 7?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto, for preventive reasons, yes, the code of the original poster should have an `else if` there.

On the other hand, a string can't both be equal to `"save"` and to `"load"`, which means that if there is a bug in the (incomplete) code of the original poster, then it is probably not there.

BTW: if `mode` isn't equal to `"save"` and also not to `"load"`, then their `if`'s are noops.

Comment: @Juraj, it is not clear what problems you have with the code. Actualy, what is the expected behavior of your program? Do you have unbounded lines to read? Are the `load` commands only meant to be typed after all the `save`s have been issued? There are many things that are not clear from your question. Please clarify those points and it will become easier to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the input / output given, that the rest of your code is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{ 
  char mode[444], key[333], data[222];
  while (1)
  while ((scanf("%s %s", mode, key)) != EOF) {
    if (strcmp(mode, "save") == 0) { 
      getchar();
      fgets(data, 100, stdin);
      printf("SAVE %s %s %s\n",mode,key,data);
    //root = save(root, key, data);
    //root = balance_RBT(root, blc);
    }
   if (strcmp(mode, "load") == 0) {
     printf("LOAD %s %s\n",mode,key);
     // load(root, key); 
     }
   }
 }
```

So, whatever problems you are experiencing, they have to deal with either your definition of mode,key and data, or the implementation of the tree insert/search.